# SQLite if column exists solution?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a trigger that dealing with some column in a table.

The trigger must handle the error that would occur if such a column doesn't exist.

Is it possible? I searched the web with no such solution because "if exists" command doesn't exists in SQLite.

**EDIT:**
Example for a trigger (requested in the comment):

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
    AFTER UPDATE ON table_1
    BEGIN
       IF exist (select col_1 from table_1) 
          BEGIN 
            update table_1 set col_1='1' where id = '2'
          END
    END
```

If col_1 doesn't exists it will make an error.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a query that would trigger this trigger?

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, [triggers can execute only normal SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html); there are not any programming constructs like `IF`.

If you do want to execute dynamic code, you have to register your own user-defined function (how this is done depends on what language/driver you're using), and call it from the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name
AFTER UPDATE ON table_1
BEGIN
    SELECT my_custom_function();
END
```

In your function, you can then check the table structure with a [`PRAGMA table_info`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) query and execute the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I don't understand. where in the DB can I write a function?

Comment: To repeat myself: this depends on what language/driver you're using.